# map method for iterating array fetched from firebase

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, firebase, dictionary

here you see the data to fetch from firebase: [https://blog-5c8a0.firebaseio.com/posts.json][1]

```
{
  "-MJCgbiP2K-se7imNbuF": {
    "author": "Ruben",
    "caption": "kipburger met biet en muntmayo",
    "cook": "30",
    "date": "2020-10-09T14:10:01.694Z",
    "description": "In onze vorige post maakte we #hamburgerbroodjes. Het hamburgerbroodje is uiteraard onafscheidelijk verbonden met de burger die er tussen gaat. Dus vandaag volgt het recept die de burger en het broodje samenbrengt. Eet smakelijk alvast!",
    "ingredients": "",
    "prep": "30",
    "sequence": 1,
    "servings": "4",
    "tags": ["bieten", "burger"],
    "title": "kipburger",
    "utensils": "4 grote kommen en bakpapier"
  },
  "-MJChesMyzz9oY2e-LmB": {
    "author": "Emma",
    "caption": "liefdesbrood met een spinazie en portobelloburger",
    "cook": "niet",
    "date": "2020-10-09T14:14:36.735Z",
    "description": "Geïnspireerd op het Liefdesbrood gerecht van de Bagel Bakery & Burgers maken wij een portobello & spinazieburger. Uiteraard serveren wij de burgers met zelfgemaakte liefdesbrood.\nLaatst is SugarSnaps bij de Bagel Bakery & Burgers geweest om brood te bakken met de eigenares (voor de post klik hier door: #liefdesbrood van de Bagel Bakery & Burgers). Zij vertelde ons hoe wij liefdesbrood konden bakken. Een brood rijk aan smaak met haar krokante zoutkorst en de zaadjes door het deeg. Wij konden het niet laten het liefdesbrood zelf ook te bestellen. Het brood kwam met mascarpone, gewokte wilde spinazie, pijnboompitjes, Parmezaanse kaas en geroosterde cherry tomaatjes en een heerlijke tapenade van eekhoorntjesbrood.",
    "ingredients": "",
    "prep": "30",
    "sequence": 1,
    "servings": "2",
    "tags": ["burger", "liefdesbrood", "liefdesbrood"],
    "title": "liefdesburger",
    "utensils": "Grill en wok "
  }
}
```

It is an array of 2 objects. in my Reactapp I store each object as a post. I can iterate through it with `posts.map(post=> post)`.

each object has a tags-array consisting of more elements (key: value pairs, I believe. don't fully understand). Why can't a map through with `post.tags.map(tag=> tag)`? It keeps saying ×

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

Does anybody have the correct iterating function for me??

I fetch the objects with this function and store it in posts. But the 'tags-array' stays unhandled. ow do I  parse the JSON and select its values, inside the post for the "tags"?

```html
useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://blog-5c8a0.firebaseio.com/posts.json")
      .then((response) => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((res) => {
        const fetchedPosts = [];
        for (let key in res) {
          fetchedPosts.push({
            ...res[key],
            id: key,
          });
        }
        dispatch({ type: "SET_POSTS", posts: fetchedPosts });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        // dispatch(failedFetchingPosts());
      });
  }, []);
```

```html
import React, { useReducer, useEffect, useState } from "react";

//CONTAINERS
import FullPost from "./FullPost";

//COMPONENTS
import Aux from "../../hoc/Auxiliary/Auxiliary";
import Post from "../../components/Post/Post";
// import Updated from "../../components/UI/Updated";
import Modal from "../../components/UI/Modal/Modal";

const postsReducer = (currentPosts, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_POSTS":
      return action.posts;
    default:
      throw new Error("Should not get there");
  }
};

function BlogOverview(props) {
  const [posts, dispatch] = useReducer(postsReducer, []);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [currentPost, setCurrentPost] = useState("");
  const [editMode, setEditMode] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://blog-5c8a0.firebaseio.com/posts.json")
      .then((response) => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((res) => {
        const fetchedPosts = [];
        for (let key in res) {
          fetchedPosts.push({
            ...res[key],
            id: key,
          });
        }
        dispatch({ type: "SET_POSTS", posts: fetchedPosts });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        // dispatch(failedFetchingPosts());
      });
  }, []);

  console.log("lala", posts);

  const onViewCurrentPost = (id) => {
    setCurrentPost(id);
  };

  const onRemoveBackdrop = () => {
    setCurrentPost(null);
    setEditMode(false);
  };

  const onToggleEditMode = () => setEditMode((prevMode) => !prevMode);

  const postAdded = () => {};

  let postList = posts.map((post) => {
    return (
      <Post
        style={{ textAlign: "center" }}
        post={post}
        key={post.id}
        viewPostHandler={() => onViewCurrentPost(post.id)}
      />
    );
  });

  let currentFullPost = currentPost && (
    <Modal removeBackdrop={onRemoveBackdrop}>
      <FullPost
        currentId={currentPost}
        editModeHandler={onToggleEditMode}
        editMode={editMode}
      />
    </Modal>
  );

  return (
    <Aux>
      {currentFullPost}
      <section className="Posts">{postList}</section>
    </Aux>
  );
}

export default BlogOverview;
```

```html
import React, { useReducer, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import image from "../../assets/images/kipburger.jpeg";
import Aux from "../../hoc/Auxiliary/Auxiliary";
import Button from "../../components/UI/Button/Button";

const postReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_FULLPOST":
      return action.fullPost;
    case "ADD_TAG":
      return action.fullPost;
    default:
      throw new Error("Should not get there");
  }
};

function FullPost(props) {
  const [post, dispatch] = useReducer(postReducer, {});
  const [tagMode, setTagMode] = useState(false);
  const [newTag, setNewTag] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://blog-5c8a0.firebaseio.com/posts/${props.currentId}.json`)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((res) => dispatch({ type: "SET_FULLPOST", fullPost: res }))
      .catch((err) => {});
  }, []);

  const onToggleTagMode = () => {
    setTagMode((prevMode) => !prevMode);
  };

  const onChangeTagHandler = (newValue) => {
    setNewTag(newValue);
  };

  const onSubmitTag = () => {
    onToggleTagMode();
    const tags = post.tags.concat(newTag);
    const updatedPost = { ...post, tags: tags };
    fetch(`https://blog-5c8a0.firebaseio.com/posts/${props.currentId}.json`, {
      method: "put",
      body: JSON.stringify(updatedPost),
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    })
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((res) => dispatch({ type: "SET_FULLPOST", fullPost: res }));
  };

  let description = props.editMode ? (
    <textarea
      className="full-post__description--edit-mode"
      onChange={(event) => onChangeTagHandler(event.target.value)}
      defaultValue={post.description}
    />
  ) : (
    <p>{post.description}</p>
  );

  console.log(post.tags.map);

  let tags = post.tags.map(tag=> tag)

  return (
    <Aux>
      <div className="full-post">
        <div className="full-post__image">
          {tagMode ? (
            <Aux>
              <input
                className="infront-image"
                type="text"
                onChange={(event) => onChangeTagHandler(event.target.value)}
              />
              <Button
                icon="FiCheck"
                text="save tags"
                handleOnClick={onSubmitTag}
              />
            </Aux>
          ) : (
            <Button
              icon="FiEdit2"
              text="edit tags"
              handleOnClick={onToggleTagMode}
            />
          )}
          <img src={image} alt="kipburger" />
        </div>
        <div className="full-post__textbox">
          <h1>{post.title}</h1>
          <p>{post.author}</p>

          <p>
            <strong>bereiding: </strong>
            {post.prep} min || <strong>wachten: </strong>
            {post.cook} || <strong>personen: </strong>
            {post.servings}
          </p>
          <p>
            {" "}
            <strong>benodigdheden: </strong>
            {post.utensils}
          </p>
          <p>
            {" "}
            <strong>serveertips: </strong>
            {post.servetips}
          </p>

          {description}

          <Button
            icon="FiEdit2"
            text="edit posts"
            handleOnClick={props.editModeHandler}
          />
          {props.editMode ? <p>Hello</p> : <p>What?</p>}
        </div>
      </div>
    </Aux>
  );
}

export default FullPost;
```

Comment: Is a document that contains two arrays? Or a collection that has two documents? And firestore or the realtime db?

Comment: Please share the whole code, ie. where you iterate over the posts, and I guess inside that, over the tags.

Comment: `posts` is not an array; you have to parse the JSON an select its values, before you can use the `map()` function.

Comment: As @S.Ramjit mentioned, the posts.json file has an object which has two properties with the post objects as values. It would be helpful if you could post the entire function code here.

Comment: fetching the post is an asyncronous operation; you are trying to operate on post before it is retrieved from the server. Anyway, posts.tags is already an array, therefore the operation `let tags = post.tags.map(tag=> tag)` makes no sense.

Comment: I got it. So it was as @secan said an async issue. .map doesn't work if undefined. WIth the first render the tags are undefined. With the second render tags is not undefined. Probably not the nicest solution but I added a turnarystatement: `{post.tags && post.tags.map(tag=><p>tag</p>)}`